# How to start GNOME session from chainroot?

Tags: virtualization

I have used cowbuilder to set-up a chainroot with ubuntu+1 (essentially minimal ubuntu installation in a sub-folder, which you can "change" into, for example for building packages in a clean environment).

How can I start gnome-session from there? Ideally I want it to appear on a new VT. I hope to achieve poor-man's virtualisation ;-)

Comment: Please elaborate, what is "chainroot"?

Comment: @Source Lab: Done =)

Comment: Does chainroot have a homepage somewhere? I can't find it in the Ubuntu repos and though I do find a few references through Google, nothing very helpful.

Comment: @ROger Pate: google for debootstrap, pbuilder, cowbuilder. In essence you know you have `/` mounted? with chainroot command you can pretend your `/` is temporarly somewhere else, which allows you to run "bootstrapped" debian/ubuntu releases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a combination of `startx` and `/etc/X11/Xsession`, as long as you've got the necessary trees bind-mounted (I'd guess that you'll need `/dev`, `/sys`, and `/proc`)

Chroot into your… chroot and run

```
sudo startx bash
```

which should give you an X term with a shell.  To start a GNOME session you can simply run

```
/etc/X11/Xsession
```

from that shell.

You should be able to get this on the VT of your choice; check out the man page for `startx` for this, and other potentially interesting options.

Note that this doesn't make for a secure chroot - since `/proc` and `/sys` and `/dev` are mounted in the chroot a sufficiently advanced malicious user break out of the chroot with ease.

Answer (score 1):

I have used such a setup a long a time ago.
I believe it was just as simple as starting X from the chroot specyfing a different display name:

```
startx -- :1
```

Switch to it with: CTRL-ALT-F9