# Move existing Ubuntu 13.04 to a virtual machine on Windows 8

Tags: windows, virtualization

I currently have dual boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.04 on a Dell XPS 13 laptop. Ubuntu has a major problem with display drivers (screen backlight) that I haven't been able to solve, so I'm looking for alternatives.

I would like to use some kind of virtual machine program on Windows that will boot up my existing Linux install into a fullscreen window. I am after one of two scenarios:

1. Something that would mount and boot my existing Linux install from where it is, so I can still dual-boot if required. This seems like the cleanest option, and would make life very simple indeed.
2. A way to make a copy of EVERYTHING from my existing Ubuntu install onto a virtual machine, leaving me free to delete the Linux partitions, and use Ubuntu via VM only.

Scenario 1 is preferred.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the first scenario:**

You can try to start Ubuntu in a [chroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot). For this you should install any Linux on your VM. Mount all your Ubuntu partitions there.

Then mount your `/proc` `/sys` and `/dev` and `startx` as explained in [How to start GNOME session from chainroot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2332/how-to-start-gnome-session-from-chainroot)

```
mount -t proc none path_to_chroot/proc/
mount -t sysfs none path_to_chroot/sys/
mount -o bind /dev path_to_chroot/dev/
```

Here is a bash script to run chrooted Ubuntu, which you can edit for your needs:

```
#!/bin/bash
mount --bind /dev /media/disk/dev
mount --bind /proc /media/disk/proc
mount --bind /sys /media/disk/sys
mount --bind /dev/pts /media/disk/dev/pts
cp /etc/resolv.conf /media/disk/etc/resolv.conf
chroot /media/disk
```

**For the second scenario:**

Check out these questions on SuperUser

- [Make image of existing Ubuntu installation for VirtualBox](https://superuser.com/questions/216052/make-image-of-existing-ubuntu-installation-for-virtualbox)
- [Linux-live-cd-flash-preinstalled](https://superuser.com/questions/206357/linux-live-cd-flash-preinstalled)

Also using [this tutorial](http://www.maketecheasier.com/backup-ubuntu-with-remastersys/) you should do a `remastersys backup`, that means that you will do a full system backup including your home folder, all applications and all your data into `.iso` image. Put this image on USB hard drive, or just to Windows NTFS partition. Then you can install your Ubuntu in VirtualBox using this `.iso` file.

Comment: Thanks so much! Any chance of making this a little more step-by-step for a newbie? I've installed Ubuntu on a new VirtualBox machine. Do I need to do anything first before I start running the commands you listed above?

Comment: I'm stuck on "Mount all your Ubuntu partitions there". I don't know how to access those partitions from VirtualBox running on Windows...

Comment: I update answer providing more easy solution for you

Comment: Thanks! Remastersys worked perfectly. I had to install using `deb http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu precise main` even though I am running Raring. I also had to empty my trash, downloads folder, and a few other things to get my total filesize down small enough to fit on an iso.