# Switching easily between windows 8 and Ubuntu

Tags: windows-8

Is there an easy way to switch between Ubuntu and Windows 8 without restarting? I need both for my work and restarting everytime seems cumbersome but also inefficient. I've heard that it was possible to do so for windows 7 though Vmare

Machine: Lenovo g500

Comment: This works: http://askubuntu.com/questions/356137/move-existing-ubuntu-13-04-to-a-virtual-machine-on-windows-8

Answer (score 0):

Just install one of the two operating systems, Linux or Windows, download Virtual Box on this [link](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and install. After that run Virtual Box and install Windows or Linux as a virtual machine.

The only thing is that one OS would be a Virtual machine.